# Fill DataExtension based on percent query

Tags: marketing-cloud

We use data extensions for our A/b testing and some are fairly custom list setups for the A/b's. So long story short I would like to be able to use SQL percentages to setup my A/B extensions but based on percentages so that it will be fluid as the mast list total changes.

I know you could do in SQL like (first 50%)

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT SubscriberID
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SubscriberID) AS RN,
                COUNT(*) OVER()                   AS Cnt
         FROM   MasterSubscriberDE)
SELECT SubscriberID
FROM   CTE
WHERE  RN BETWEEN 0.0 * Cnt AND 0.5 * Cnt
```

Is there a way of achieving something similar to this with exactarget queries?

Currently I use static row ranges so would be nice if I could change to be more fluid (so I don't have to manually update).

```
SELECT SubscriberID
FROM (
    SELECT SubscriberID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SubscriberID) AS RowNum
    FROM MasterSubscriberDE
) AS RowRange
WHERE RowRange.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 25000
```

Comment: What would be even better (but I don't think it is possible) is if there is one DE with the list and then I can just use a filter to send against the DE based on percentage count. That way I would never even need to refill the sub DE's. But I do not think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you want to retrieve a set percentage....

```
SELECT TOP 50 Percent SubscriberID  
FROM (
    SELECT SubscriberID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SubscriberID)
AS RowNum  
    FROM MasterSubscriberDE
) AS RowRange
```